# How to write table blob field to file using ArcObjects?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcobjects, c#, table

I have a table with blob field and some others as well. I am trying to read blob field and save it to file using IBlobStream, and the thing compiles. The problem comes up in run-time, when calling blobStream.SaveToFile() method, saying:

```
'object' does not contain a definition for 'SaveToFile'
```

the following code:

```
int blobFieldID= table.Fields.FindField("MODEL_NAME");
int nameFieldID= table.Fields.FindField("MODEL");
ICursor cursor = table.Search(null, true);
IRow row = cursor.NextRow();
while (row != null)
{
    IBlobStream blobStream = (IBlobStream)row.get_Value(blobFieldID);
    blobStream.SaveToFile(@"C:\TEMP\" + row.get_Value(nameFieldID) + ".tbx"); //error
    row = cursor.NextRow();
}
```

When i hover mouse over SaveToFile method it says:

```
(dynamic expression)
This operation will be resolved at runtime
```

I can't figure out what's the problem in here

Comment: Hi, is this sample running on such as console application?

Comment: @Darksanta No, It is an action on button click - ESRI.ArcGIS.SystemUI.ICommand.OnClick()

Comment: hmm, it looks like strange problem. Usually these kind of error happen when using dynamic keyword. Is this able to get other field values correctly?

Comment: Ensure that "Embed interop types" is turned off for all Esri references. Second, try `IMemoryBlobStream` instead of `IBlobStream` (this really shouldn't make a difference though).

Comment: @Petr Krebs Ohh right... I were making this in new project, and forgot to set Embed interop types to false so they would no longer by dynamic - problem solved, Thanks! You can actually make it as an answer I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that "Embed interop types" is turned off for all Esri interop assembly references.